# Как сделать текст на той же строке с#

Tags: c#, консоль

Всем привет! Учил с# полтора года назад, уже много чего забыл. Хотел сделать, что бы текст выводился на той же строке. Допустим. Загрузочный экран:

```
Console.WriteLine(“Loading”);
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine(“.”)
```

Я хочу что бы точка вывелась на той же строке. Или:

```
Console.WriteLine(“Enter password:);
pas = Console.ReadLine();
```

Я хочу что бы текст вводился на той же строке. Помогите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого есть метод `Console.Write`, то же, что и `Console.WriteLine`, но без переноса строки.

```
Console.Write(“Loading”);
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.Write(“.”)
```

```
Console.Write(“Enter password:);
pas = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write("Enter password: ");
pas = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: ок. постараюсь)